# Get shapefile from ArcGIS online for QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online

How do I download shapefile information from ArcGIS online and access it in QGIS. An example shapefile that I would like to obtain is linked below:

https://morgancountyco.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Solutions/s2.html?appid=c3891aec54f04f29b8d1da10a5c6afbd

Answer (score 1):

You would need to be accessing the feature layer and seeing if the user has enabled it to allow for export and then exporting the shapefile. You wont be able to do this with the application provided.

Answer (score 0):

That's a map from Morgan County, Colorado. The map title is *Water District - Northern Colo Water Consa*. It appears to display parcel data within the Northern Colorado Water Conservation District. Clicking on a parcel on the map gives a popup with this information:

- 12-digit `Parcel Number`
- 7-character alphanumeric `Account Number`
- `LAST NAME, FIRST NAME` (presumably the parcel owner(s), but it doesn't actually specify)
- a broken link to "view assessor data", in this format: http://www.co.morgan.co.us/assessor/taxweb/account.jsp?accountNum=xxxxxxx. Clicking on the link takes you to the [main page](https://www.colorado.gov/morgancounty) for Morgan County, Colorado.

[Morgan County GIS](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/morgancounty/geographic-information-systems-gis) provides a grand total of **two** shapefiles for download:

1. Parcels ([direct download link](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/morgancounty/atom/155671))
2. Roads ([direct download link](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/morgancounty/atom/155666))

It sounds like the parcel shapefile is the one you want. If not, you can request the data from the Director of GIS for Morgan County (there's contact information on the Morgan County GIS page).